# How to insert variables in a table using VBA MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a program which works with xml files. I read some information out of the file and want to insert it into a table which is already created. By now I have two arrays, one contains all of the ClassData which I need, the other contains the ValueData I need.

Every Class has one value, as you can see in the example above.
Our ClassData Array contains at first the project id ( in this example ABC) and then many other strings, which i read out before and are saved in the array.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (PROJECT_ID,.......) SELECT 'ABC', '..' ... ;
```

Of course this code is wrong but maybe it helps you to understand my problem.

I think the easiest way would be something like a loop, but I have no idea how to make this happen.

I hope somebody can help me.

Please excuse my English, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Hi @ChosenFew, welcome to Stack Overflow!

It's a while since I used Access VBA but I seem to recall there was a way to save an import specification and then use it programatically to import an XML file into a temporary table.   From there you can select the values you want into your database.

Something a bit like this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/run-a-saved-import-or-export-specification-6969e099-4573-40f0-a1e0-f3042bddb640

Comment: Agree with @TimOgilvy, try to use built-in import methods for XML files first, it could be much easier to use them